# opening csv files - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv 
with open('loan.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
      spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='', quotechar='|')      
      for row in spamreader:
          print ','.join(row)
```

On running this i get the followinh error :

> File "loan.py", line 5     print ','.join(row)
>                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you're using Python 3 then you need parentheses around the thing you're printing. `print` is a function in Py3, not a statement.

Comment: what are the contents of csv file ?

Comment: You're opening the file correctly. The error is unrelated to that

Comment: Csv file contains simple data about a loan, I also tried using print() .

Comment: Was it still a SyntaxError when you used `print()`?

Comment: Because it should also complain that `delimiter` is empty, and it needs to be a 1-character string (like `,`). And that you need to use `'r'` mode instead of `'rb'` mode to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

if this is python 3 print requires to be called like this print(). If your own a *nix system make sure when you run python that python 2.7 is being executed and nit python3